# Slice Data by Discount Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a measure in Power BI that calculates the customer discount for whatever customer or product is selected. I want to add a slicer that will filter down the discount to the range that they want to focus on. If the user just wants to see customers that range from 5% to 15% discount, they can set the slicer to show that range. I know this is possible when opening the filters pane, but I want to have the option for users directly on the screen.

[image: Example in Filters Pane]

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You need to use another table that would hold slicer values and create a slicer on that table. Then, you need to account for that in your measure, that is make it react to the selected values within that table.

Answer (score 0):

first generate the series (Format : Percentage)

Modelling ---> New Table

```
Percentage = GENERATESERIES ( 0.01, 1.01,0.01 )
```

Then use this as slicer and in your calculations use it as

`max(Percentage[Value])` and `min(Percentage[Value])`

[image: Discount Slicer]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got the slicer to work. However, I'm having trouble using the MAX and MIN of Percentage[Value] in my measures. Here is the new formula I wrote for discount:

Discount 4 Scatter = 
CALCULATE([Discount], [Discount]>=[Percentage Slicer MIN]&&
[Discount]<=[Percentage Slicer MAX])

The "Percentage Slicer MIN" measure is just taking the MIN of the Percentage[value] field. Vice versa for MAX.

error:
A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Comment: @worldwidegleb sorry I didn’t have time to check here today. If you share your sample data and measures, we can help more faster.

Comment: @worldwidegleb you can try something like  
``Discount 4 Scatter =
CALCULATE (
    [Discount],
    FILTER (
        [YourTableName],
        [Discount] >= MIN ( [Percentage Slicer] )
            && [Discount] <= MAX ( [Percentage Slicer] )
    )
)``